# How to send a Embedded Webhook using PHP [Discord]

Tags: php, json, webhooks, discord

I am trying to send a Webhook to a Discord channel when a User fills out a form on my website, I would really like it to be embedded, however I am having trouble doing that. I have managed to post the Webhhook fine using "content", however I just cannot get it embed it.

```
$Embed = {
  "username": "Kick Report",
  "embeds": [{
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "Victim",   
        "value": "Change Victim Later",
        "inline": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Reason",
        "value": "Change Reason Later!",
        "inline": true
      },
      {
        "name": "Caller",
        "value": "Change Caller Later"
      },
      {
        "name": "Date",
        "value": "Change Date Later"
      }
    ]
  }]
};


$data = array("content" => $Embed, "Kick Report" => "Webhooks");
$curl = curl_init("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 return curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this code:

```
<?php

// Replace the URL with your own webhook url
$url = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/0000000/ABCDEFGH....";

$hookObject = json_encode([
    /*
     * The general "message" shown above your embeds
     */
    "content" => "A message will go here",
    /*
     * The username shown in the message
     */
    "username" => "MyUsername",
    /*
     * The image location for the senders image
     */
    "avatar_url" => "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/972154872261853184/RnOg6UyU_400x400.jpg",
    /*
     * Whether or not to read the message in Text-to-speech
     */
    "tts" => false,
    /*
     * File contents to send to upload a file
     */
    // "file" => "",
    /*
     * An array of Embeds
     */
    "embeds" => [
        /*
         * Our first embed
         */
        [
            // Set the title for your embed
            "title" => "Google.com",

            // The type of your embed, will ALWAYS be "rich"
            "type" => "rich",

            // A description for your embed
            "description" => "",

            // The URL of where your title will be a link to
            "url" => "https://www.google.com/",

            /* A timestamp to be displayed below the embed, IE for when an an article was posted
             * This must be formatted as ISO8601
             */
            "timestamp" => "2018-03-10T19:15:45-05:00",

            // The integer color to be used on the left side of the embed
            "color" => hexdec( "FFFFFF" ),

            // Footer object
            "footer" => [
                "text" => "Google TM",
                "icon_url" => "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/972154872261853184/RnOg6UyU_400x400.jpg"
            ],

            // Image object
            "image" => [
                "url" => "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"
            ],

            // Thumbnail object
            "thumbnail" => [
                "url" => "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/972154872261853184/RnOg6UyU_400x400.jpg"
            ],

            // Author object
            "author" => [
                "name" => "Alphabet",
                "url" => "https://www.abc.xyz"
            ],

            // Field array of objects
            "fields" => [
                // Field 1
                [
                    "name" => "Data A",
                    "value" => "Value A",
                    "inline" => false
                ],
                // Field 2
                [
                    "name" => "Data B",
                    "value" => "Value B",
                    "inline" => true
                ],
                // Field 3
                [
                    "name" => "Data C",
                    "value" => "Value C",
                    "inline" => true
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $hookObject,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ]
]);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

?>
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/83itgm/does_anyone_know_how_to_send_embeds_from_php_to_a/

Comment: What token? Are you sure I need to do this? It works fine when I don't use the embed, and instead just put something such as: "This is a test".

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit annoying, but where do I put this?

Comment: Okay, that works fine now! The only issue now is how to get the "Value" of each field to display what ever is in a certain Variable, for example:

             `"fields" => [

                [
                    "name" => "Victim",
                    "value" => $Victim,
                    "inline" => true
                ],`

How do I get the "Value" to be whatever is in the $Victim variable?

Comment: $Victim is array or Object? If using array, simply get the key, `$Victim['data']`.

Comment: It's an object, from the Form. `$Victim = $_POST["VictimInput"];`

It works if I normally post it or whatever, just not when it's as the "Value" of the embed. 
However, when I fill out the form, it says this: `{"embeds": ["0"]}` when it didn't say this when it worked.

Comment: You need to var_dump to check the data object. Using foreach to assgin data to `embeds `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177657/discussion-between-james-smith-and-khoa-truongdinh).

Comment: This is not working anymore because you're not using headers correctly. It has to be `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ["Content-Type: application/json"]`